# Intuition on why the doubling map on $S^1$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, dynamical-systems

I was asked to show that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f: x \mapsto 2x$ induces a continuous map $\bar{f}:S^1 \to S^1$ for $S^1 = \mathbb{R}/(2\pi\mathbb{Z}) = [0, 2\pi)$. I was told to think in terms of projecting the unit circle onto the reals and arguing that $\bar{f}$ is a composition of continuous maps. I didn't fully understand this argument and in fact can't get myself to even believe this map is continuous.

If we were working over the reals, I agree it's obviously continuous, but the fact that $\bar{f}$ is defined over a clopen quotient field seems problematic for me. This is because a continuous map, intuitively in my mind, is one that guarantees that small perturbations in the input space lead to small perturbations in the output space. If I think of the unit circle however, the doubling map at input $\pi$ gives $2\pi \cong 0$ in the output space. However, at input $\pi - \epsilon$, it gives $2\pi - \epsilon$ which is very far from $0$. So by decreasing the input by an infinitesmal amount, the output "jumped" from $0$ to $2\pi - \epsilon$, so I don't see how such a map could be continuous.

I would appreciate clarity on the "composition" argument, and how that relates to my mistaken graphical intuition about "small perturbation."

Comment: It's not obvious to me what your "doubling map" is. Does it send $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ to $(\cos 2\theta, \sin 2\theta)$? Or $x \in \mathbb{R}$ to $2x$, inducing a map on the circle?

Comment: Updated to make the question clear, thanks.

Comment: Do you know the universal mapping property of the quotient?  I think that's all this is.

Comment: I don't know what that is. I'm looking for a simpler/more intuitive answer. Thanks, though.

Comment: I think my original comment was a bit confused. Those two maps are the same one - $\mathbb{R}$ is your argument space; doubling that just doubles your argument. If $q$ is the quotient map sending $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ to $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$, then $q \circ f \circ q^{-1}$ is well-defined and sends $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ to $(\cos 2\theta, \sin2\theta)$.

Comment: The false equation $\mathbb{R}/(2\pi\mathbb{Z}) = [0, 2\pi)$ has perhaps led you astray.

Comment: Oh I see, @LeeMosher yes, if that equality doesn't hold then what exactly is $\mathbb{R}/(2\pi\mathbb{Z})$? How do I picture it? I wrote that equality based on analogy with the fact that I know $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} = \{ 0, 1\}$, for example.

Comment: Yes, @LeeMosher I now see that $S^1$ is in fact $[0, 2\pi]$ with the ends "glued" together so that $0 \cong 2\pi$, and of course $S^1 \not\cong [0, 2\pi)$ because they have different topological properties like compactness. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, it is probably better to identify $S^1$ with $S^1 = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1\} = \{e^{it} : t \in [0, 2\pi)\} \subset \mathbb{C}$ equipped with the induced metric from $\mathbb{C}$. I think this identification is a homeomorphism. In this case, the doubling map $x \to 2x$ is the map $f(e^{it}) = e^{2it}$. Equivalently, $f(z) = z^2$. Since $z^2$ is continuous, $f$ is continuous.

This explains why $2\pi - \varepsilon$ is close to $0$: the point on the unit circle with angle $2\pi - \varepsilon$ is close to the point with angle $0$.

Comment: I see. So the key thing is that I cannot think of $S^1$ as $[0, 2\pi)$ because those are NOT homeomorphic, and so properties like continuity of the latter do not necessarily transfer to the former (because there is no continuous map between the two). Thinking as the complex unit circle makes this clear. Is this the canonical way to visualize $S^1$?

Comment: @TanishqKumar Yes this seems to be the most common way to use $S^1$ in analysis. The way you wrote $S^1 = \mathbb{R} / (2\pi\mathbb{Z})$ suggests that you are equipping $S^1$ with the quotient topology. So formally, you have to show that $\mathbb{R} / (2\pi\mathbb{Z})$ with the quotient topology is homeomorphic to $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| = 1\}$.